# Pull target rotates leg wrong direction

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints

I followed a tutorial to rig my character, but the pull target for the leg makes it bend the wrong direction. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe switch to Edit mode and try to bend it in the right direction, then back to Pose mode and test

Comment: Edit the armature or the object?